# Will Google Optimize keep testing my page variants if I push a change to the landing page?

Tags: ab-testing, google-optimize, optimizely

Two parts to this question:

1. If I have a landing page with a simple hero where the primary text is being A/B tested, but I decide I want to change the control text programmatically and deploy, will Google Optimize keep testing even though the control content changed?
2. Same landing page with same hero w/ primary text being A/B tested, but I decide I want to wrap the hero and secondary text in a div with some styles that I defined, will Google Optimize be smart enough to find where my tested component is?
3. Bonus question: When does google give up and say "this guys being a cheeky bugger let's stop trying to test his landing page so we don't accidentally test the wrong piece of text"

I know I'm kind of describing an extreme case here, but this is more so out of curiosity, I'd like to know what page updates will render the page untestable without manual effort.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, if you change the control of your AB Test, it will continue to test.  Because it's not watching for content changes in the control.  I'd advise against this, as it may skew your results.  Maybe better to make the change to the control and then restart your test.
2. In the latest version of Google Optimize, your can edit variants in tests which are already live.  Optimize will not stop you from publishing those changes.
3. It will never say that.  World is your oyster :)

Comment: Thanks! quick follow up: What if I completely change the layout so that the selector path of my element is different? Will Google Optimize get confused?

Comment: @NikitaJerschow - No it won't know at all. It's not that smart.  It's literally only good at running AB Tests - Control vs V1 vs V2 etc etc.  It definitely won't watch for changes. It will keep collecting data throughout and despite all your changes, view your entire test, from beginning to end, as one test :)